# Count lead duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, count, lead

I have the below table

Table A:

```
row_number  id    start_dt    end_dt   cust_dt    cust_id
   1        101    4/8/19     4/20/19   4/10/19   725
   2        101    4/21/19    5/20/19   4/10/19   456
   3        101    5/1/19     6/30/19   4/10/19   725
   4        101    7/1/19     8/20/19   4/10/19   725
```

I need to count "duplicates" in a table for testing purposes.

Criteria: 
Need to exclude the start_dt and end_dt from my calculation.
It's only a duplicate if `lead` row is duplicated. So, for example row 1, row 3 or 4 are the same but only row 3 and 4 would be considered duplicates in this example.

What I have tried:
`rank` with a `lead` and self join but that doesn't seem to be working on my end.

How can I count the id to determine if there are duplicates?

Output: (something like below)

```
count    id 
  2      101
```

End results for me is to have a count of 1 for the table

```
count  id
 1     101
```

Comment: Why do you have two columns called `id`?

Comment: @GMB updated the last id to cust_id

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,start_dt,end_d,cust_dt,    cut_id ORDER BY id,start_dt,end_d,cust_dt,    cut_id) as RN and then everything which has RN > 1 is already present, so you can easily count those.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number` analytical function as following (gaps and island problem):

```
Select count(1), id from
(Select t.*, 
        row_number() over (order by row_number) as rn,
        row_number() over (partition by id, cust_dt, cust_id order by row_number) as part_rn
   From your_table t)
Group by id, cust_dt, cust_id, (rn-part_rn)
Having count(1) > 1
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b52b26246c3743d510ce5fbb25bb00c)

Cheers!!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I think it will yield output as 2 which is required.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0765a8b789595105e5ce2f5ae6a3b375) .

Comment: Ohh yes, Updated the answer with changed `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of a duplicated row is: *the `CUST_ID`in the `lead` row (with same `id` order by `row_number`) equalst to the current `CUST_ID`*,

you may write it down simple using the `LEAD`  analytic function.

```
select ID, ROW_NUMBER, CUST_ID,
case when CUST_ID = lead(CUST_ID) over (partition by id order by ROW_NUMBER) then 1 end is_dup
from tab

        ID ROW_NUMBER    CUST_ID     IS_DUP
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101          1        725           
       101          2        456           
       101          3        725          1
       101          4        725
```

The aggregated query to get the number of *duplicated rows*  would than be

```
with dup as (
select ID, ROW_NUMBER, CUST_ID,
case when CUST_ID = lead(CUST_ID) over (partition by id order by ROW_NUMBER) then 1 end is_dup
from tab)
select ID, sum(is_dup) dup_cnt
from dup
group by ID

        ID    DUP_CNT
---------- ----------
       101          1
```